# Can not install v8js extension for SSR using Laradock

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, server-side-rendering, laradock, v8js

I am trying to manage server side rendering using [react-laravel](https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-laravel) which requires [v8js extension](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js).My working environment is a [laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock).

I have enabled V8JS installation in laradocks **.env** file:

```
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS=true
```

I have rebuild my workspace and php-fpm images via docker-compose

```
docker-compose build workspace php-fpm
docker-compose restart
```

And when i am trying to install the react-laravel in the container im getting such error:

```
Problem 1
 - reactjs/react-php-v8js dev-master requires ext-v8js >=0.1.3 -> the requested PHP extension v8js is missing from your system.
    - talyssonoc/react-laravel v0.11 requires reactjs/react-php-v8js dev-master -> satisfiable by reactjs/react-php-v8js[dev-master].
    - Installation request for talyssonoc/react-laravel 0.11 -> satisfiable by talyssonoc/react-laravel[v0.11].
```

I have lost almost all day and i am loosing hope to solve this issue.
Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Edit1

This is what running php-fpm container produce

```
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:51:02] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_soap.dll' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:51:02] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'v8js.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:51:02] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:51:02] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
php-fpm_1              | 172.19.0.8 -  06/Aug/2018:12:55:42 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:56:43] NOTICE: Terminating ...
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:56:43] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:56:56] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_soap.dll' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_soap.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:56:56] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'v8js.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/v8js.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:56:56] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php-fpm_1              | [06-Aug-2018 12:56:56] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```